# Nested View in Theme Views using Fuelphp

Tags: fuelphp, theming

I have working with Fuelphp and done some tiny apps, Now i am moving to bigger one, now i am stuck with this.

I have enabled theme in fuelphp and it is working perfectly, In my App there is a Top Nav bar, In Nav bar there is 3 drop down notification system like facebook & also search option. So i have created top_nav partial. I want to make the search and notification system in partial inside partial, to making it more modular, so i created another partial of top_nav_search and top_nav_notif . Both partials need some variables to transfer from controller, How i do that. My variables are passing to top_nav only. Not top_nav_search or top_nav_notif.

How can i add partial inside the partial.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set_global` on your view, and then the exposed variable will be available everywhere.

```
$view->set_global('some_data', $some_data);
// instead of
$view->some_data = $some_data;
```

Also, when using `set_partial`, you can specify a `View` instance instead of the path for the view. That way you can pass variables directly into the `View` instance specified to `set_partial`. Though I'm not sure it solves your problem. Still, here's an example:

```
$view = View::forge('nav/search');
$view->some_data = $some_data;
$theme->set_partial('top_nav_search', $view);
```

**Edit:** I wrote `View::forge`, but more appropriate would've been to write `$theme->view` in this example. Like this:

```
$view = $theme->view('nav/search');
$view->some_data = $some_data;
$theme->set_partial('top_nav_search', $view);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that using `set_global` adds overhead as the global data is copied between views with the current implementation.

Comment: @AshiqueZakariyyaP What do you mean by APP/View? `Theme::view()` (or `$theme->view()`, since it's not static, I guess) has a very similar signature compared to `View::forge()`, you can use that as well in the second example. Do you mean that does not work? @Uru I didn't know that, that sounds terrible :D

Answer (score 0):

Answer Found:

using View Class will not work with theme. It will search for APP/View folder.

we have to use

```
echo Theme::instance()->view('partials/partial_file')->set_safe('var', $this->get('var'));
```

found working

Comment: It's actually the same that I wrote in my second comment to complement my answer to avoid a misunderstanding. `Theme::instance()->view()` actually returns a `View` class. I actually made the mistake to write `View::forge()` instead of `$theme->view()`, but I thought you'll figure out, since you are working with the `Theme` class. I didn't know you didn't use `set_partial()`, but echo a `View`, which removes a layer of flexibility, but might work better for you. I'll edit my answer to correct this mistake.